# How to remove multiple users from a dynamic distribution group in exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010

I was able to remove one user using this command:

```
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity "All Staff" -RecipientFilter {((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and -not(Name -like 'Employment'))}
```

But I have more than one mailbox that I want to remove.  Is it possible to add another mailbox into the above command?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some common property you can use to filter against all the recipients you have to exclude, you will need to exclude them one by one using multiple exclusion filters.

Comment: This is the command used in case someone else needs help: Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity DDGName -RecipientFilter {((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and -not(Name -like 'Display Name 1') -and -not(Name -like 'Display Name 2') -and -not(Name -like 'Display Name 3') -and -not(Name -like 'Display name etc.'))}

Answer (score 1):

A manageable solution would probably be one that meant you didn't have to keep coming back to change the recipient filter every time a new candidate for exclusion was created.

I had to implement a recipient filter the other day for a management scope. The filter was based on a security group. So from the security group angle, you could create a security group and manage your exclusions using that. For example, your filter would look like:

```
{((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and -not(MemberOfGroup -eq 'AllStaff_Exclusion_Group'))}
```

Equally, you could just use the SG to include staff members, removing the need for a complicated filter.If it helps, [heres a list of all filterable properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738157%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx). There are many, so it's possible you could find one that your excluded recipients have in common.